# MySQL query is slow on big table

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by

I dont have other ideas on how to optimize this query, runs about 2,5 sec with goodsXML table over 2 million rows. It looks like order by is slowing a lot, but i cant remove it. Also, it depends a lot on how many items selected here `gx.categoryID IN(892)`, because later another tables joins this items set. I cant make joins after this option, because joined tables perform in where clauses.

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(gx.id,598)) citySort,gx.dateCreated lastModifiedSince,IF(DATE(gx.dateModified)>=(IF((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) BETWEEN 0 AND 6),DATE(NOW() -INTERVAL 6 HOUR),DATE(NOW()))) OR DATE(gx.dateModified)>=DATE(NOW()),1,0) isActual,
        gx.id,p.producerName,gx.categoryID,gx.name,CONCAT('::',gxi.imageName) images,IF(CONCAT('::',gxi.imageName)!='',1,0) imExist,gx.price,gx.oldPrice,gx.oldPricePt,gx.sourceUrl,IF(s.offerPostingType='XML',IF(s.alternateName!='',s.alternateName,s.name),CONCAT(u.lastName,' ',u.name)) shopName,s.logoName,
        s.id shopID,s.active shopActive,s.offerPostingType,c.titleAdd,'Москва' cityName,
        IF((s.cityID='598' AND s.deliveryByCity=1) OR (sa.cityID='598' AND sa.deliveryByCity=1) OR (s.deliveryByMRCities LIKE '%^598^%' AND s.deliveryByMR=1),1,0) deliveryInYourCity,
        IF(s.deliveryByCityAll=1 OR (s.cityID='598' AND s.deliveryByCity=1) OR (sa.cityID='598' AND sa.deliveryByCity=1) OR (s.deliveryByMRCities LIKE '%^598^%' AND s.deliveryByMR=1),1,0) deliveryByCity,
        IF(s.deliveryByMail=1,1,0) deliveryByMail,
        IF(s.deliveryBySelfAll=1 OR (s.cityID='598' AND s.deliveryBySelf=1) OR (sa.cityID='598' AND sa.deliveryBySelf=1),1,0) deliveryBySelf
        FROM goodsXML gx
        JOIN category c ON c.id=gx.categoryID
        LEFT JOIN producer p ON p.id=gx.producerID
        JOIN shop s ON s.id=gx.shopID
        LEFT JOIN shopAddress sa ON sa.shopID=s.id
        LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=s.userID
        LEFT JOIN goodsXMLImages gxi ON gxi.goodsXMLID=gx.id AND gxi.isMain = 1

        WHERE 1=1 AND (s.cityID='598' OR s.deliveryByCityAll=1 OR s.deliveryBySelfAll=1 OR s.deliveryByMail=1 OR sa.cityID='598' OR (s.deliveryByMR=1 AND s.deliveryByMRCities LIKE '%^598^%')) AND (s.isPaying=0 OR u.balance>0) AND gx.categoryID IN(892)
        GROUP BY gx.id

        ORDER BY isActual DESC,imExist DESC,gx.PPC DESC,gx.payPrior ASC,citySort DESC
        LIMIT 0,40
```

Explain is following:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
| ID | SELECT_TYPE | TABLE |  TYPE  |         POSSIBLE_KEYS          |       KEY       |    KEY_LEN     |          REF           |        ROWS        |             EXTRA              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | c     | const  | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY         | 4              | const                  | 1                  | Using temporary; Using filesor |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | gx    | ref    | ixGroupNameCategoryIDShopIDPro | ixCategoryID... | ixCategoryIDid | 4                      | const              | 82005                          |
|    |             |       |        | ducerID                        |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | s     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | deliveryByMR    | PRIMARY        | 4                      | vsesrazu.gx.shopID | 1                              |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | sa    | ref    | shopKey                        | shopKey         | 5              | vsesrazu.s.id          | 2                  | Using where                    |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY         | 4              | vsesrazu.s.userID      | 1                  | Using where                    |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY         | 4              | vsesrazu.gx.producerID | 1                  |                                |
|    |             |       |        |                                |                 |                |                        |                    |                                |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | gxi   | ref    | over                           | over            | 4              | vsesrazu.gx.id         | 1                  |                                |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Show create table for goodsXML:

```
CREATE TABLE goodsXML (
 id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 localID char(255) NOT NULL,
 groupID char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 dateCreated datetime NOT NULL,
 dateModified datetime NOT NULL,
 dateModifiedPrice datetime NOT NULL,
 name char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 nameHash char(32) NOT NULL,
 groupName char(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 newGroupName char(255) NOT NULL,
 url char(255) NOT NULL,
 sourceUrl char(255) NOT NULL,
 categoryID int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
 producerID int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 authorID int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 shopID int(6) NOT NULL,
 XMLUrlOrder tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 price float(12,2) NOT NULL,
 oldPrice float(12,2) NOT NULL,
 oldPricePt smallint(3) NOT NULL,
 description text,
 descriptionHash char(32) NOT NULL,
 descriptionForGroup text NOT NULL,
 imExist tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 imagesForGroup tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 videoHighlight text NOT NULL,
 videoSiteUrl char(255) NOT NULL,
 videoChannelUrl char(255) NOT NULL,
 plusesMinuses text NOT NULL,
 toIndex tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 isRST tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 isReplica tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 status tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 comment char(255) NOT NULL,
 daysLeft tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 PPC float(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 payPrior tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4',
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 UNIQUE KEY ixGroupNameCategoryIDShopIDProducerID (shopID,localID),
 KEY ixGroupNameCategoryID (groupName,categoryID),
 KEY ixStatusShopID (status,shopID),
 KEY ixCategoryID (categoryID),
 KEY authorID (authorID),
 KEY ixDateModified (dateModified,imExist),
 KEY daysLeft (daysLeft),
 KEY sourceUrl (sourceUrl),
 KEY ixCategoryIDid (categoryID,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4218880 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: 1. Remove the `group by`. If you get more than 1 row per gx.id (by `shopAddress`?), the `if`-term that uses `shopAddress` will use a random row, so you might get wrong results. If you get 1 row per gx.id, you don't need the `group by`. 2. The `order by` will indeed slow your query down, as it cannot use an index. Try to precalculate: `imExist` could be set by a trigger (you may already do that, but the column gets hidden by your query that redefines `imExist`). Maybe it's possible for `isActual` too (worst case: by an hourly script, idealy: finding a value that gives you that order naturally).

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPLAIN` shows that it needs to scan about 82K rows of `gx`.  There are apparently about that many rows with `categoryID = 892`, correct?  Most of the rest is straightforward `JOINs`.

- Don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB.
- `INT(6)` -- the `(6)` means nothing.  Perhaps you meant `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`?  `INT` is 4 bytes; `MEDIUMINT` is 3.
- Are you 'always' searching by `category`?  If so, make use of InnoDB's "clustered" PK by switching to `PRIMARY KEY (categoryID, id), INDEX(id)` and chuck the two existing indexes starting with `categoryID`.
- Don't use `CHAR` unless the column is truly fixed length; use `VARCHAR`.
- Don't use `FLOAT(m,n)`, it can lead to subtle rounding errors.  For Money, use `DECIMAL(m,n)`; for Scientific values, use `FLOAT`.
- `ORs` defeat optimizations.  See if you can redesign the schema to avoid some of them.
- What is `LIKE '%^598^%'`?  Do you have a list of numbers in that column?
- After switching to InnoDB, decrease `key_buffer_size` to only 30M and increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of available RAM`.